# Can you define a Caffe layer to do mean subtraction to an Input layer for a deployed model?

Tags: python, neural-network, transform, caffe, pycaffe

You can provide the `mean_file` parameter to an `Input` layer as part of the `transform_param` block, such as:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 224 dim: 224 } }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
}
```

but for an `Input` layer it appears that this transformation is just [ignored without warning](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/VHXXFmNSiv8/szbjdMKpAQAJ).

When inspecting the other [data layer types](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html), it seems that none of them are capable of using a plain `Input` layer as their bottom (input) layer, and so none of these layers can be used to apply a mean subtraction after the fact.

There is also a [`Bias` layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/bias.html), but I cannot make sense of its documentation and it does not appear to accept a binaryproto file.

Suppose I am constrained so I can only express mean subtraction in the proto file. I cannot do it in C++ or Python ahead of time before passing in the input, and I cannot write it as a custom layer or a `Python` layer.

Given this constraint, how can I achieve mean subtraction by a binaryproto file in the Input layer -- either by defining another layer after or it, or some other means?

Comment: i think caffe has a batch normalization layer,if you want proper mean substraction you can use it and set the batch size to one which would be slow but i guess bacth normalization will be generally useful ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222815/image-mean-subtraction-vs-batchnormalization-caffe

Comment: `"Input"` layer is usually used in `deploy.prototxt` meaning you are going to manually, externally supply the net with input data. How are you feeding this particular net? In most cases the process feeding the net in test time also handles the various required transformations.

Comment: @Shai Yes, as I mentioned in the question, this operation is meant to happen in a deployed model. In this case, it is a system where you can submit the trained model weights file, the layer proto file, and *data* files, but you cannot submit additional code. So you can't add a new Python layer or control any preprocessing before the image is passed to the network. I would also like to do a resizing operation in the Caffe Input layer too, but there is a different workaround in this case for that.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you can have an input layer which "top" is the *minus* of `'imagenet_mean.binaryproto'`, then you can use [`"Bias"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/bias.html) layer to subtract the mean:

```
layer {
  name: "mean_subtract"
  type: "Bias"
  bottom: "raw_data" # shape 1-by-3-by-224-by-224
  bottom: "minus_imagenet_mean" # assuming shape 3-by-224-by-224
  top: "data"
  bias_param { axis: 1 } 
}
```

Working with `batch_size: 1`, you can also do the same subtraction using [`"Eltwise"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/eltwise.html) layer.

---

**Update:**
Okay, it seems like your issue is "where the hell am I going to bring `"minus_imagenet_mean"` blob?!"
Have you considered using [`"Parameter"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41578532/1714410) to store `"minus_imagenet_mean"`?

```
layer {
  name: "minus_imagenet_mean"
  type: "Parameter"
  top: "minus_imagenet_mean"
  parameter_param { shape { dim: 3 dim: 224 dim: 224 } }
  param { lr_mult: 0 decay_mult: 0 }
}
```

Once you define this layer, you can use [`net surgery`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) to init this parameter. Then store it to `caffemodel` alongside all the other parameters of the net and you should be okay.

Comment: This doesn't explain how it would use `imagenet_mean.binaryproto` to perform the mean subtraction. From the documentation it looks like a `Bias` layer requires you to supply a mean array (with broadcast-compliant shape) as input, but again, I cannot do that in this case. You have to assume I have nothing but the binaryproto, and I can't do anything with it except mention it in some type of layer.

Comment: After the updates, it is still unclear how a top layer named "minus_imagenet_mean" could be used. Data layers cannot take input from an `Input` layer, and it's not clear how to pass the binaryproto as a subtraction argument to some other custom subtraction layer. "Net surgery" is also completely unavailable given the constraints of my problem mentioned in the question: just able to pass the proto, caffemodel, and data files to another system that can consume and run models. I cannot manipulate what Python code is called ahead of time (or else I would just do mean subtraction in Python).

Comment: @ely **offline stage** (to be carried once by you *before* passing `caffemodel`): in this stage, you should open the net in python, read the `'imagenet_mean.binaryproto'` and using net surgery, set `net.layer[minus_imagenet_mean].blobs[0].data[...] = -imagenet_mean`. Now you save the resulting caffemodel. **Next** you upload the saved caffemodel that has `-imagenet_mean` stored in the file as one of the layers' parameters to your system. **online stage** the updated caffemodel reads the `-imagenet_mean` stored in the uploaded caffemodel and subtract the mean as you expected.